# Spring + java - InvocationTargetException

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, pom.xml

So when I try to run my project with mvn spring-boot:run I get this build failure.

[image]

Through Google searching I think my problem lies in my pom.xml file and my spring versions. However I can't figure out where my exact problem lies. Here is my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>mavenproject1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>  
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>mavenproject1</name>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

<!--    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>-->

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!--Spring--> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--MONGO-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>          
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!--skal dette bruges?-->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>6.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

What I am trying to build is a spring boot application which connects to a mongoDB and has a rest api. Oh and uses elasticsearch.

Hopefully someone can see where I'm going wrong? Thanks in advance!

** Edit: error with error log:

[image]

** updated log:

[image]

Comment: Most likely you have a Java version mismatch. Check the Java on console.

Comment: My java version is 1.8.0_121. How can I know if it's a wrong version? and which is the correct?

Comment: There is no correct, there is incompatible. Try to change to 1.8 in your pom.xml(maven-compiler-plugin).

Comment: hmm didn't work. I have tried to run the maven with the -e and I have updated my post with the error log. Maybe that can tell you a bit more?

Comment: Oh, I so you use spring 3, in this case there is incorrect. It doesn't work with java 8.

Comment: which should I use then?

Comment: Probably 4 try with this version 4.3.10.RELEASE

Comment: I tried updating the spring versions, however I still get the error. I've updated the post with the new error log. Can you see where I'm still going wrong?

Comment: Now it's javaee try to change to 7. Also instead of finding out the problem with each of your dependencies consider Veeram's answer.

Comment: it worked. Thanks Oleg.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to define dependencies manually for each component.

Just define mongo and elastic search starter dependency and spring boot will pull all the necessary compatible dependencies required for component.

Replace your dependencies section with something like

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!--Spring--> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

       <!--Mongo--> 
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
       </dependency>

      <!--Elasticsearch-->
      <dependency>                          
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
     </dependency>

</dependencies>
```